# How to avoid duplicate string in a spinner?

Tags: android

I have a spinner and an edittext, I want the edittext to get the spinner text when pressed, but the result is that the text will be doubled a lot.

```
private EditText etTormenta2;
Spinner spnTormentaIni2;

String tormentaColumna1[]={"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"};

spnTormentaIni2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnTormentaIni2);


ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapter21=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.combos_tormentaarena,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        spnTormentaIni2.setAdapter(adapter21);

        spnTormentaIni2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                int start =etTormenta2.getSelectionStart();
                final String str2 ="\"ColumnStart\": "+tormentaColumna1[i]+",";
                etTormenta2.getText().insert(start, str2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by doubled a lot?And can you elaborate exactly what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the edittext with the name etTormenta2 not to duplicate the string str2 text when the spinnner is pressed

Comment: Isn't is simple.Just check the content of edittext by etTormenta2.getText().toString().contain(tormentaColumna1[i]).If if doesnot contain, append the text to the string and set the edit text gy calling setText()

Comment: My edittext with the name etTormenta2 already previously added other text but in this occasion duplicates the values of the string str2